# HtmlUnit doesn't give output

Tags: java, eclipse, htmlunit

I installed HtmlUnit (gargoyle software) in Eclipse J2EE and ran a code in it and the output was 
"HtmlUnit
Copyright (c) 2002-2011 Gargoyle Software Inc. All rights reserved.
Version: 2.9
"
What is happening? what should I do

Comment: If you like to get an answer you have to show your code. And please use the latest version (2.28 at the moment)

Comment: Hi, I am using HtmlUnit and everything is good this time. I want to scape a single element using webpage.getFirstByXPath(Xpath).  _HtmlElement element = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id='findCompanies']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]/a");
             String text = element.asText();_ but it returns nullpointer exception. I copied XPath from chrome. Please help

Comment: hi i have another doubt, i want to use same session again after termination. Can i do that by saving the cookies and re-reading them in next time execution? if yes, how can that be done?

Comment: Every WebClient has an associated CookieManager. You can read/save all cookies before closing the client and add them back after opening a new one.